# How to trigger an event when all the controllers are ready in Spring Context?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I am trying to execute a code in PostConstruct of one my controllers. But this action is such that it will also cause one other controller from this same module to be triggered by some other external module. I observed that the other controllers are not ready when our code in postConstruct gets executed.

I also tried out using ApplicationContext listener on ContextRefreshed and ContextStarted event, but still all the controllers don't seem to be ready by this time if some external modules try to contact them.

What am I missing? Is there any hook available to trigger a method execution when all the controllers are ready for current module?

Answer (score 3):

*Context refreshed* event should work unless you are using LAZY initialization (which is not enabled by default).

**Be sure to listen for correct context event.** There are two (or more) refresh events - one for root context and one for each servlet context.

Comment: I tried out ServletContextListener and ApplicationListener but still the request to the controller from external module is giving 404 error at that point. May the method which you are suggesting is actually working but the servlet container seems to block requests to any of it's controllers till the event handler itself has completed it's job. Therefore we are currently relying upon some thread sleep delay in the external module before contacting any of the controllers of current module.

Comment: I have a feeling you are doing something else then what you are asking for in your question. What do you mean by "request from external module"? You are correct that application container will not let servlet handle any request till it is fully initialized. But how is this connected to your question?

Comment: The code which I want to run after the controllers have been initialized, will trigger some external application to immediately contact this module.

Comment: That is an interesting use-case... will try to replicate the behaviour in the evening. Btw. what server are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat